# How do I create a keyup event in the keydown that will send a certain key with a keyup handler to the browser

Tags: jquery, keydown, keyup

**SOLVED!**

EG, when a keydown handler sees my pressed Tab key, I want this keydown handler to create a keyup event and send this Tab keypress to the browser so that my keyup handler is executed

```
$(.elem).keydown {

// create keyup Event and send this event to
// browser which will then execute my keyup handler

}

$(.elem).keyup {

   // sent here

}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
$(.elem).keydown {

    $(.elem).trigger("keyup");

}
```

Comment: You can't inject keystrokes and mouse clicks from Javascript.  Why don't you just call the `keyup` handler?  That would have the same effect.  It's just a function.

Comment: Your idea works except for keydown repeat = event.repeat